# Automatically saving on FocusLost sometimes stops working for a gvim window

Tags: gvim, autocmd, save

In my `~/.vimrc` I have at the moment:

```
autocmd BufLeave,FocusLost * nested silent! wall
```

Which most of the time works as I would like, however sometimes it seems saving simply stops working (for a particular `gvim` window, all tabs): when I alt-tab away from the window changes aren't saved. It does seem as though changing to a different tab saves the changes to the buffer, so perhaps `FocusLost` in particular is not firing?

The only way to get it working again is to close gvim and re-open my files.

I'm not sure how to go about starting to debug this.

**EDIT**: I've noticed that if I do a `:autocmd FocusLost * echo "lost focus"` in a broken gvim session nothing is printed when I alt-tab away, while the message is printed as expected in windows where my autosaving is working as expected.

Comment: Define « not working »

Comment: According to [`:h :wall`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Awall) `Write all changed buffers.  Buffers without a file name cause an error message.` so since you use `silent!` is it possible that the problem occurs when you open a buffer without a file name and don't see the relevant error because of `silent`? If so what I would try would be to use [`:h :bufdo`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Abufdo) to apply `silent w` on all buffers, this way if one fails because it can't be saved the other should still get saved.

Comment: @statox Thanks. I've got a window open that's exhibiting this behavior now. I did a `:bw <n>` for a few buffers that didn't exist (tmp files I'm not sure where they came from), but it didn't change the behavior.

Comment: I've also encountered this occasionally; using GVIM 8.1 on Ubuntu 16.04. Restarting Vim fixes the problem.